# possibility of memory overwrite using pointers in c?

Tags: c, pointers, overwrite

I've written my own `getline` function following K&R c book

```
void getline(char * const str) 
{
  int c;
  char* temp = str;
  while ((c=getchar()) != '\n') {
    *temp = c;
    temp++;
  }
  *temp = '\0'
}
```

and it's used to initialize strings

```
char *str1, *str2;
printf("Type string 1: ");  
getline(str1);
printf("Type string 2: ");  
getline(str2);
```

Just wonder that, what if the memory locations `str1` and `str1` point to are very close, then `getline(str2)` overwrites contents in string 1?

It that's possible how could I avoid it? THANKS!

## Update:

Yes the program stops executing the above code snippet but the code below works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
  char* str;
  char* temp = str; 
  int c;
  while ((c=getchar()) != '\n') {
    *temp = c;
    ++temp;
  }
  *temp = '\0';
  printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Here the `str` is also uninitialized character pointer but why deoesn't it give me an error?

Comment: `char *str1, *str2;` are uninitialized. So change to `char str1[128], str2[128];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is [*Undefined Behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

## Explanation:

You declared two pointers to `char`:

```
char *str1, *str2;
```

but you haven't initialized them. They point to some "random" memory location as they are uninitialized.

Then, you pass `str1` and `str2` to `getline` and here:

```
char* temp = str;
```

`temp` points to where `str` points to. Then, in the loop,

```
*temp = c;
```

you write to this memory location. This writes into an invalid memory location. And invokes [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

## Fix:

1. You can use an automatic array with a fixed size:

   ```
   char str1[101], str2[101];
   ```

   Note that you should add a check in the loop in the `getline` function which breaks the loop when the user has entered 100 characters so that there won't be a [*buffer overflow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).
2. A better solution would be to use dynamic memory allocation. You need to use `malloc` and `realloc` for that. These functions require the `stdlib.h` header.

   **Fixed code** *(untested)*:

   ```
   char* getline() 
   {
     char* str;
     int c, size = 10, counter = 0;

     str = malloc(size); /* Allocate `size` memory */

     if(str == NULL)
     {
       printf("malloc failed to allocate memory");
       exit(-1); /* Exit the program */
       /* Or
       return NULL;
       */
     }

     while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { /* Added check for EOF as well */
       str[counter] = c;
       counter++;

       if(counter == size)
       {
         char* temp = str; /* Backup in case realloc fails */
         size += 10; /* Which is the same as `size = size + 10` */
         str = realloc(str, size); /* realloc size(20) memory */

         if(str == NULL) /* If realloc failed */
         {
           printf("reallocing memory failed");
           str = temp; /* str is NULL, retrieve the original contents */
           break; /* Break out of the loop */
         }
       }
     }

     str = realloc(str, counter + 1); /* realloc `counter + 1` memory */

     str[counter] = '\0';
     return str;
   }
   ```

   and in the calling function,

   ```
   char* str1 = getline();
   if(str1)
     puts(str1);
   free(str1);


   char* str2 = getline();
   if(str2)
     puts(str2);
   free(str2);
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you have a look at my update question?

Comment: @SouthParker Undefined Behavior(UB) , means that anything could be the result. It might work as expected. It might stop working as expected when you add a simple `printf`. It might crash. It might seg-fault. It might do something else etc etc

Comment: Cheers! Very appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

`str1` and `str2` are not initialized thus it'll be undefined behaviour. You can access to not allowed memory which will crash your program.

You have to allocate enough memory for each pointer and pass its size to get line function to ensure you write only in allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

`str1` and `str2` are uninitialized.Right now you write (`*temp = c;`) at invalid (or unauthorized) memory location invoking **UB** .

First you need to allocate memory to `str1` and `str2`  .

```
str1=malloc(100);     // check return 
str2=malloc(100);
```

To be able to write into that memory location.

> Just wonder that, what if the memory locations str1 and str1 point to are very close, then getline(str2) overwrites contents in string 1?It that's possible how could I avoid it?

And as far as you concern , memory allocated by these `malloc` won't overlap (will be two different contagious memory blocks) , so if you also tend to write beyond these memory location ,you will invoke **undefined behaviour** (*if you are lucky segmentation fault* ) . So, IMHO, there won't be any case of `str2` over-writing `str1`.